# Running emulated android device as unrooted

Tags: android, emulation, root

This question probably has an answer somewhere but it seems to be buried by people with the opposite problem.

*I am running an app with the emulator (using IntelliJ and Android Studio but with the same SDK). The app throws an intentional error due to "non-secure device". How do I run the emulator device as **not** rooted?*

Please just let me know if and what additional info would be required to answer my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think only GenyMotion runs as rooted. The AVD manager didn't have rooted images last time I used it.

Comment: As it turns out, what I am trying to do is not possible. It isn't "rooted" per-say. It is failing a security check that includes root file system access checks and checks for various black listed packages. Oh well! 
On the plus side, I have real devices I can use instead.